# Не срабатывает .attr()

Tags: jquery, attr

Использую метод .attr, чтобы передать атрибут data-y элементу .inner.
Блоков .content на странице множество, поэтому обращаюсь не напрямую по имени класса.

```
.content
    .inner
        // Здесь блоки, которые должны переключаться
    .arrows
        .js-arrow-up
        .js-arrow-down

$('body').on('click', '.js-arrow-up', function() {
    var $container = $(this).parents().eq(1).find('.inner');
    var current_pos = $container.attr('data-y') ? parseInt($container.attr('data-y')) : 0;
    var shift = 200;
    if (current_pos > 0) {
    if (current_pos - shift < 0) current_pos = shift;
    $container.css('transform', 'translateY(-' + (current_pos - shift) + 'px)')
    $container.attr('data-y', current_pos - shift);
}
}).on('click', '.js-arrow-down', function() {
    var $container = $(this).parents().eq(1).find('.inner');
    $('.inner').attr('transition');
    var current_pos = $container.attr('data-y') ? parseInt($container.attr('data-y')) : 0;
    var shift = 200;
    var max = ($container.find('.inner').length - 3) * shift;
    if (current_pos < max) {
    if (current_pos + shift > max) current_pos = max - shift;
    $container.css('transform', 'translateY(-' + (current_pos + shift) + 'px)')
    $container.attr('data-y', current_pos + shift);
}
});
```

Атрибут не передается.
$element определяет правильно. В консоли ошибок нет.

Подозреваю, что неправильно определяю элемент, но ошибку найти не могу.

Comment: где находится элемент `'.inner'`?

Comment: внутри общего родителя .content, вместе со стрелками. То есть в строке $container = $(this).parents().eq(1).find('.inner'); часть $(this).parents().eq(1) ведет к родителю.

Comment: Вместо `.attr('data-y')`, можно использовать `.data('y')`

Comment: .data('y') не сработал, к сожалению.

Comment: @IrinaEzhova Добавьте в вопрос разметку html.